# Put computer to sleep and have it ask for password on wake

Tags: terminal, sleep-wake

How do I put computer to sleep and have it re-awake asking for a password?

I'm looking for a terminal command to do this.

I tried `pmset sleepnow` did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [multiple answers to the question](https://superuser.com/questions/313425/toggle-ask-for-password-after-screensaver-sleep-or-the-delay-in-10-7-using-ter) of how to programmatically enable 'Ask for password after sleep or screensaver' -- the option that appears in the Security preferences panel.

[image]

Once you've enabled that option, you can use the following command to run an AppleScript to sleep the computer:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to sleep'
```